# Merging records in a Numpy structured array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a Numpy structured array that is sorted by the first column:

```
x = array([(2, 3), (2, 8), (4, 1)], dtype=[('recod', '<u8'), ('count', '<u4')])
```

I need to merge records (sum the values of the second column) where

```
x[n][0] == x[n + 1][0]
```

In this case, the desired output would be:

```
x = array([(2, 11), (4, 1)], dtype=[('recod', '<u8'), ('count', '<u4')])
```

What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Please edit this question to reflect the structured array you gave in a comment: `array([(2, 3), (2, 8), (4, 1)], dtype=[('recod', '<u8'), ('count', '<u4')])`.  You existing question looks more like a 2d array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Dicakar's` answer cast in structured array form:

```
In [500]: x=np.array([(25, 1), (37, 3), (37, 2), (47, 1), (59, 2)], dtype=[('recod', '<u8'), ('count', '<u4')])
```

Find unique values and count duplicates:

```
In [501]: unqA, idx=np.unique(x['recod'], return_inverse=True)    
In [502]: cnt = np.bincount(idx, x['count'])
```

Make a new structured array and fill the fields:

```
In [503]: x1 = np.empty(unqA.shape, dtype=x.dtype)
In [504]: x1['recod'] = unqA
In [505]: x1['count'] = cnt

In [506]: x1
Out[506]: 
array([(25, 1), (37, 5), (47, 1), (59, 2)], 
      dtype=[('recod', '<u8'), ('count', '<u4')])
```

There is a `recarray` function that builds an array from a list of arrays:

```
In [507]: np.rec.fromarrays([unqA,cnt],dtype=x.dtype)
Out[507]: 
rec.array([(25, 1), (37, 5), (47, 1), (59, 2)], 
      dtype=[('recod', '<u8'), ('count', '<u4')])
```

Internally it does the same thing - build an empty array of the right size and dtype, and then loop over over the dtype fields.  A recarray is just a structured array in a specialized array subclass wrapper.

There are two ways of populating a structured array (especially with a diverse dtype) - with a list of tuples as you did with `x`, and field by field.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Thanks for helping out OP on this! I wasn't really familiar with the structured arrays thing.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`np.unique`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) to get an ID array for each element in the first column and then use [`np.bincount`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html) to perform *accumulation* on the second column elements based on the IDs -

```
In [140]: A
Out[140]: 
array([[25,  1],
       [37,  3],
       [37,  2],
       [47,  1],
       [59,  2]])

In [141]: unqA,idx = np.unique(A[:,0],return_inverse=True)

In [142]: np.column_stack((unqA,np.bincount(idx,A[:,1])))
Out[142]: 
array([[ 25.,   1.],
       [ 37.,   5.],
       [ 47.,   1.],
       [ 59.,   2.]])
```

---

You can avoid `np.unique` with a combination of [`np.diff`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html) and [`np.cumsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html) which might help because `np.unique` also does sorting internally, which is not needed in this case as the input data is already sorted. The implementation would look something like this -

```
In [201]: A
Out[201]: 
array([[25,  1],
       [37,  3],
       [37,  2],
       [47,  1],
       [59,  2]])

In [202]: unq1 = np.append(True,np.diff(A[:,0])!=0)

In [203]: np.column_stack((A[:,0][unq1],np.bincount(unq1.cumsum()-1,A[:,1])))
Out[203]: 
array([[ 25.,   1.],
       [ 37.,   5.],
       [ 47.,   1.],
       [ 59.,   2.]])
```

Comment: I am getting the following error:
`Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/krlk89/abc.py", line 8, in <module> unq1 = np.append(True,np.diff(x[:,0])!=0) IndexError: too many indices`

Comment: @krlk89 What's the shape of `x`? `x.shape` output?

Comment: `>>> x
array([(2, 3), (2, 8), (4, 1)], 
      dtype=[('recod', '<u8'), ('count', '<u4')])
`

`>>> x.shape
(3,)
`

Comment: @krlk89 Do something like `A = np.column_stack((x['recod'],x['count']))` and then use the solutions, assuming A as the input to the solutions? Or in the solution codes, use `x['recod']` in place of `A[:,0]` and `x['count']` to replace `A[:,1]`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, while I get the right numbers, it seems to me that I am losing my array structure? The structure is important to me, I need to write the array to a binary file as 8 byte unsigned integer, 4 byte unsigned integer pairs.

Comment: You need to build a new structured array, using `unqA` and the count to fill the 2 fields.  It can copy the `dtype` from your original array.

Comment: @hpaulj could you please give a more in-depth guide on how to do this. Thanks!

Comment: I added an answer based off this one, adapted to structured arrays.

Answer (score 2):

[`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/) makes this type of ["group-by" operation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) trivial:

```
In [285]: import pandas as pd

In [286]: x = [(25, 1), (37, 3), (37, 2), (47, 1), (59, 2)]

In [287]: df = pd.DataFrame(x)

In [288]: df
Out[288]: 
    0  1
0  25  1
1  37  3
2  37  2
3  47  1
4  59  2

In [289]: df.groupby(0).sum()
Out[289]: 
    1
0    
25  1
37  5
47  1
59  2
```

You probably won't want the dependency on pandas if this is the only operation you need from it, but once you get started, you might find other useful bits in the library.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I tried this and got an error message: pastebin.com/mA6fDT3u

Comment: I see you changed the format of your array.  In that case, use `df.groupby('recod').sum()`.

Comment: Thanks! It works now, but how can I get back the structure of my initial array?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`np.reduceat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduceat.html). You just need to populate where `x[:, 0]` changes which is equivalent to non zero indices of `np.diff(x[:,0])` shifted by one plus the initial index 0:

```
>>> i = np.r_[0, 1 + np.nonzero(np.diff(x[:,0]))[0]]
>>> a, b = x[i, 0], np.add.reduceat(x[:, 1], i)
>>> np.vstack((a, b)).T
array([[25,  1],
       [37,  5],
       [47,  1],
       [59,  2]])
```